# After Install cPanel/WHM, I am unable to Connect VPS by SSH and http also

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, cpanel, vps

I am new to GCP. But I worked in DO and AWS before. I am facing a problem with WHM/cPanel after installation. Before installation, all were working fine. Many times I have created VPS's and installed Cpanel, but facing the same issue. Let me say, what I have done

Step 1: Created VPS (Last Time used 2Core/2GB/40GB HighCPU)
Step 2: Created Firewall rules. All ports are open. See the SS.
[Firewall All Ports Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibx4r.jpg)

Step 3: Installed Cpanel and restarted.
And the problem also started. See the SS
[Putty SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaIrG.jpg)
But VPS status is still active.

Error log details after the serial port on

```
    {
insertId: "2"
jsonPayload: {
bootCounter: "7"
lateBootReportEvent: {
policyMeasurements: [
0: {
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
pcrNum: "PCR_0"
value: "UcMj3gwMaU9GAc3QK+tY/xNin3Q="
}
1: {
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
value: "Er3aqUYRu824aO8z1X8qtoEpW2Q="
pcrNum: "PCR_4"
}
2: {
pcrNum: "PCR_7"
value: "jwk4ZGvqD/g7cbCA762EALidNFw="
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
}
3: {
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
pcrNum: "PCR_8"
value: "0/tPqa2xXWl3ROpTP0AatzlcMFc="
}
4: {
value: "+gtFIVYcXa9ikrzd/E7ZviBgGyk="
pcrNum: "PCR_9"
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
}
]
policyEvaluationPassed: false
actualMeasurements: [
0: {
value: "UcMj3gwMaU9GAc3QK+tY/xNin3Q="
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
pcrNum: "PCR_0"
}
1: {
pcrNum: "PCR_4"
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
value: "lCgv/4+1crEv6/WJgRQVhxOymmY="
}
2: {
value: "UYMZY5f0arZfbSqQAj63F+ZYD2I="
pcrNum: "PCR_5"
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
}
3: {
value: "jwk4ZGvqD/g7cbCA762EALidNFw="
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
pcrNum: "PCR_7"
}
4: {
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
pcrNum: "PCR_8"
value: "B4F2Zh5SJkmkObemKhtCI7af8js="
}
5: {
pcrNum: "PCR_9"
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
value: "x+cBMEFidufBRQ5pVn96tDDwOOo="
}
6: {
value: "t6ZIJd2dKbwZGzbxurU5X9kexUw="
pcrNum: "PCR_14"
hashAlgo: "SHA1"
}
]
}
@type: "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent"
}
resource: {
type: "gce_instance"
labels: {
project_id: "black-stone-host"
zone: "us-central1-a"
instance_id: "8581418053009736601"
}
}
timestamp: "2021-04-04T04:34:03.571063196Z"
severity: "ERROR"
logName: "projects/black-stone-host/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-04-04T04:34:05.581983772Z"
}
```

Comment: Stop the VM. Edit the VM instance and enable serial port. Start the VM. Note the IP address. Try to connect. Use the serial port to see the boot logs.

Comment: Already applied this method. But failed

Comment: What do the serial port boot logs show you?

Comment: Logs are updated in the post. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have solved the issue. It was network service configure issue.

Comment: @ShowketAhmed feel free to post an answer for the benefit of the community. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer